# Deserilaisation exception Spring Kafka | Corrupt message gets logged everytime server is restarted with ErrorDeserialiser

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

I have followed the below documentation https://www.confluent.io/blog/spring-kafka-can-your-kafka-consumers-handle-a-poison-pill/ to handle deserialization exceptions.
It works fine, the message gets logged and move forward, but everytime I restart the server the bad messages are logged again.
Is there a way I can skip/acknowledge the bad message once it is logged so that it doesnt get picked up again on restart the server

```
Consumer YAML 
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
    consumer:
      # Configures the Spring Kafka ErrorHandlingDeserializer that delegates to the 'real' deserializers
      key-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
    properties:
      # Delegate deserializers
      spring.deserializer.key.delegate.class: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class: org.sprngframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
```

Also, NOTE:=
**From the above, in logs I see it gives a warn that spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class is given -> but not a known config.**

Have also confgured this

```
@Bean
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfiguration {

  /**
   * Boot will autowire this into the container factory.
   */
  @Bean
  public LoggingErrorHandler errorHandler() {
    return new LoggingErrorHandler();
  }
}
```

Could someone please advise on the same

Comment: What version of Spring for Apache Kafka are you using? With recent versions (since 2.3), the offset will be committed after the error handler returns.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Seems consumer group offset isn't moving ahead
Using spring Kafka 2.5.7